# pandas group by with multiple filters

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe (df) with Twitter data and so far have programmed to create a dataframe based on usernames who have tweeted at least once in every week of 1,2,3,4 as below.

My dataframe looks like

```
    username url_dummy weeks  ...
0       a        1        1      ...
1       a        1        2      ...
2       a        1        3      ...
3       a        1        4      ...
4       b        0        1      ...
5       b        0        2      ...
6       b        1        3      ...
7       b        1        4      ...
8       c        1        1      ...
9       c        1        2      ...
10      c        1        3      ...
11      c        0        4      ...
12      d        0        1      ...
13      d        1        2      ...
14      d        1        2      ...
15      d        0        1      ...
16      e        0        1      ...
17      e        0        1      ...
18      e        0        1      ...
19      e        1        1      ...
```

```
df.groupby('username').filter(lambda x : pd.Series([1,2,3,4]).isin(x['weeks']).all())
```

Then my group by result looks like below.

```
    username url_dummy weeks  ...
0       a        1        1      ...
1       a        1        2      ...
2       a        1        3      ...
3       a        1        4      ...
4       b        0        1      ...
5       b        0        2      ...
6       b        1        3      ...
7       b        1        4      ...
8       c        1        1      ...
9       c        1        2      ...
10      c        1        3      ...
11      c        0        4      ...
```

More strictly, I want to create another dataframe that each username has tweeted with URL at least once in every week of 1,2,3,4.

I will use column 'url_dummy' (1 if at least one url is in a tweet, otherwise 0) to do so.

Then the desired group by the result is

```
    username url_dummy weeks  ...
0       a        1        1      ...
1       a        1        2      ...
2       a        1        3      ...
3       a        1        4      ...
```

So far I tried

```
df.groupby('username').filter(lambda x : (x['url_dummy'] == 1) & (pd.Series([1,2,3,4])).isin(x['weeks'])).all()
```

and it gives me an error as below.

```
TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: What does your data look like *before* any manipulations?

Comment: Most likely a typo somewhere, e.g. `(x['url_dummy'] == 1).any() & ...`

Comment: I have edited by adding sample original dataframe.